# Is it possible to add callback to addEvenlistener?

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a question, I want know if is a possible do something like this:

```
 document.getElementById('button').
addEventListener('mousedown', myCallback.bind(myCallback2));
function myCallback(e, cb){
    var data=5;
    cb(data)
    //alert("Hello from Callback");
}
function myCallback2(a){
    console.log(a)//show 5
}
```

I know of javascript, but not so

do some like this:

I CAN SOLVED IT :) with BIND()

the form that i want no, but i can example:

```
document.getElementById('button').
addEventListener('mousedown', myCallback.bind({cb2:myCallback2, btn:this}));

function myCallback(ev){
    var elem=this.btn, cb=this.cb2,

    var data=5;
    cb(data)
}
function myCallback2(a){
    console.log(a)//show 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible to add a custom callback to an EventListener via [addEventListener](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp).

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('mousedown', myCallback);
function myCallback(){
    alert("Hello from Callback");
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button" >Button</button>
```

Comment: brother i update the question for you understand better my idea